# Chequear por evento scroll

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Necesito realizar determinada accion cuando se scrollee. Para esto bastaria anadir `document.onscroll = () = { console.log("scrolling"); }`. Pero si la funcion es muy larga supongo que danaria al rendimiento. Quiero saber si hay una forma de saber si se scrolleo, a parte de anadir el `onscroll event` y cual de estas dos formas seria mas eficiente en terminos de rendimiento:

```js
this.setInterval(() => {
     console.log("is scrolling?");
}, 1000);

 document.onscroll = () => {
     console.log("scrolling");
 }
```

```html
<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.</p>

<p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.</p>

<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no</p>
```

Necesito saber en ese codigo en el intervalo si se esta ejecutando el onscroll event.

Comment: *si la funcion es muy larga supongo que danaria al rendimiento.*. ¿Vas a realizar el mismo proceso cada *px* que se scrollee? ¿Variaría en algo dicho proceso de acuerdo a la posición del scroll?

Comment: Deja el evento, el setInterval te va a quitar mas rendimiento.
Con el evento solo ejecutaras la acción al  hacer scroll, con el setInterval todo el tiempo vas a estar validando

Comment: @Lato, en mi app se va a escrollear mucho, tampoco es que se vaya a ejecutar una funcion muy grande siempre que se scrollee, pensare en usar el evento como me sugieres, pero igual quisiera saber una forma de poder hacerlo en el `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código puedes saber si en el intervalo se **EJECUTO** el evento `scroll`, ahora si lo que deseas es saber si se esta **EJECUTANDO** el evento `scroll` (tal como lo solicitas en tu pregunta) te recomiendo cambies la logica de tu programa ya que en este ultimo caso no requieres colocar un `setInterval()`, solo debes manejar lo que desees en el evento `onscroll()`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var lastEvent = {};
this.setInterval(() => {
     console.log("is scrolling?");
     if (lastEvent.type == "scroll") {
         console.log("yes!! ;))");
         lastEvent = {};
     } else {
         console.log("no.. :((");
     }
}, 1000);

document.onscroll = (evt) => {
    console.log("scrolling");
    lastEvent = evt;
}
```

```html
<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.</p>

<p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.</p>

<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no</p>
```

Espero esto te ayude, Saludos!! ;))...

**EDITO:**

```js
var lastEvent = {};
this.setInterval(() => {
     console.log("is scrolling?");
     if (lastEvent.type == "scroll") {
         console.log("yes!! ;))");
         lastEvent = {};
     } else {
         console.log("no.. :((");
     }
}, 1000);

document.onscroll = (evt) => {
    lastEvent = evt;
}
```

```html
<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.</p>

<p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas.</p>

<p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no</p>
```

Comment: Pudieras quitar el `console.log` del onscroll pls? Estaba buscando una forma de saber si actualmente se esta escroleando, no si se escroleo desde el ultimmo intervalo.

Comment: Te entiendo @Theia es por eso que copie tu código y solo le agregue lo que considere necesario para saber si se ejecuto el scroll, espero te sirva, Saludos!! ;))...